# How does windows 8.1 route the HDMI 5.1 audio data routed to nvidia display card

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, drivers, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I would like to understand the whole data flow of 5.1 sound data from a software application to the final output HDMI port.

Let's make a very simple scenario. A simple windows 8.1 program, uses some windows sound api to play a note for 1 seconds alternatively in the 5 channels looping forever.

How this data is routed to the nvidia display card HDMI, if:

1. There is a sound blaster Core3D card installed in the system
2. There is an on-board HDMI and HD audio jacks
3. There is a nvidia display card say GTX 960 installed and it is used as the display
4. An AV receiver is connected to the nvidia display card HDMI port
5. The AV receiver is ready to receive 5.1 LPCM signal

The questions are:

1. In this case, are the Sound blaster Core3D and the on-board HDMI (The display and audio capacity from the chipset) completely untouched?
2. Nvidia GTX 960 processor simply sends the digital sound data in LPCM format from windows 8.1 system unprocessed to the HDMI signal?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Unfortunately, I don’t have time to find sources that properly document this right now, sorry.

Comment: Grateful if you can share the link when you have time. Thanks.